# Is there an equivalent of the pointToLayer function in the R leaflet library

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I am new to leaflet and R.
I am trying to create interactive maps with R (leaflet and shiny). I basically need to trace a route with points on a map. the data comes from a GeoJSON file with properties which need to be used for style options. An earlier implementation with leaflet in html looks like this:

```
L.geoJson(route2aug,{
    style: function (feature) {
            return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
                },

    pointToLayer : function(feature,latlng){
               var popupContent = "Sootmass:" + String(feature.properties.sootmass);    
               var popupOptions = {maxWidth: 200};
               return L.circleMarker(latlng,{
             radius: 4,
                         fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.sootmass),
                         color: getColor(feature.properties.sootmass),
                             weight: 1,
                             opacity: 1,
                         fillOpacity: 0.8
                }).bindPopup(popupContent, popupOptions);
               }

    }).addTo(map);
```

Here,the data comes from the route2aug file which is imported as a js object. I need to replicate this in R with leaflet.
Is there a way to do the same thing in R?
The GeoJSON data file looks like this:

```
{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [77.68137666666667, 12.926686666666667]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"sootmass": 5}},{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [77.68138666666667, 12.926686666666667]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"sootmass": 10}},{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [77.681405, 12.926688333333335]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"sootmass": 15}}.......}
```

Comment: On a more abstract level, what is it you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to create an R plot (output of an algorithm) based on location when the point on the map is clicked

Comment: Like the svg example here?
http://environmentalinformatics-marburg.github.io/mapview/popups/html/popups.html#popupgraph

Comment: Yes. Something like this. But i was thinking on the lines of shiny. but this is really helpful.

Comment: @TimSalabim : Thanks for this one-stop solution. Does it take GeoJSON data as is?

Comment: yes, with `readOGR` from `library(rgdal)`

Comment: Thanks :-). Although I am not sure whether this will add the circlemarker or the default marker for the GeoJson points, but i can give it a shot.

Comment: readOGR is reading only the first element of my GeoJSON file :( . it doesnt recognize the following as valid JSON:`[{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [77.68137666666667, 12.926686666666667]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"sootmass": 5}},{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [77.68138666666667, 12.926686666666667]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"sootmass": 10}}]`

Comment: it works with this: `{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": { "brewery": "Brauerei Rittmayer", "address": "Aischer Hauptstraße 5", "zipcode": 91325, "village": "Adelsdorf", "state": "Bayern", "web": "<a href='http:\/\/www.rittmayer-aisch.de' target=\"_blank\">www.rittmayer-aisch.de<\/a>", "founded": 1422 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 10.889217, 49.71979 ] } },
]
}
`

Comment: @TimSalabim : Thanksfor the help till now. However I am facing problems again :( . I have plotted the Geojson layer as a collection of points and  am trying to plot the same graph for all points. however, I get an empty popup for most of the points. The popup has the plot image only for some points. here is what i am doing:                `mapviewOptions(basemaps = c("Thunderforest.Transport", "CartoDB.Positron",  "OpenStreetMap", "Esri.WorldImagery"))
m <- mapview(RegenEvents, popup = popupGraph(p, width = 800, height = 600))`  Could you help me figure why? TIA

Comment: I cannot help you without a reproducible example. Do you have the same amount of graphs (`length(p)`) as you have points on your map (`nrow(RegenEvents)`)?

Comment: No . length(p) =3 and there are ~4000 points in the GeoJson. But is it not possible to plot the same graph for all the points or more than one points ? Basically, repeating the plot 4K times is not feasible.

Comment: yes it is possible. As long as p is a valid **lattice** or **ggplot2** object or a list of those you should be able to pass it to `popupGraph`. But why do you want to show the same graph 4k times? Wouldn't it be better to show it separately? Also, why is `length(p)` = 3?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your patience with a noob :) Basically, I have one plot for a set of points and some different plot for another set of points and so on. The idea is to have one plot for more than one points. In my case, the popups are not being populated with the plot each time. PS: i need to check why length(p) =3

Comment: can you post a reproducible example with e.g. the `meuse` data set pretending you want a plot for each value of `meuse$soil` that highlights your problem? It is really hard to figure out what your problem is if we don't see an example

Comment: @TimSalabim Problem solved :-). Getting plot for all points on map. But still dont know why length(p) =3.typeof(p) is list. Although, this is not a problem, but i will need to understand this to get my basics right. Anyway, thanks for all your help. cheers